# Rails: Filter entire form parameters from log

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know Rails allows you to filter specific fields from the log. How do I filter an **entire form**?

I have a form for logging into banks, I get the fields from an API, and there are a thousand variations on what the password field is called: password1, token, pin etc etc. I just need to filter the form entirely because I cannot predict the password field name.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's poorly documented, but `filter_parameters` will also accept a regular expression or a lambda. To filter every field, you just need to use a regular expression that matches everything, e.g.:

```ruby
# config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb (or `config/application.rb` for Rails 3)
config.filter_parameters += //
```

It might be more useful, though, to whitelist parameters you *do* want logged, in which case you could do something like this:

```ruby
config.filter_parameters += /^((?!.*(id|first_name|last_name)).*)$/
```

Or:

```ruby
config.filter_parameters += ->(param) { param !~ /^(id|first_name|last_name)$/ }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me above shared didn't work, I preferred this thing.

```
# Whitelist the keys attributes here for which we don't need filtration.
# Currently we are supporting attribute which is exactly id or ends with id (EX: id, user_id)
WHITELISTED_KEYS_MATCHER = /id$/.freeze

# The filtered value gets replaced by this
SANITIZED_VALUE = '[FILTERED]'.freeze

Rails.application.config.filter_parameters << lambda do |key, value|
  unless key.match(WHITELISTED_KEYS_MATCHER)
    value.to_s.replace(SANITIZED_VALUE)
  end
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).