# Filter non-strings using config.filter_parameters lambda in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda, immutability

I need to filter string and non-string values for certain controllers using config.filter_parameters lambda in Rails. I'm currently using the approach below which works great for strings. The problem is that I cannot find a way to change numbers and boolean values because they are immutable unlike strings.

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters << lambda do |param_name, value, data|
  controller = data&.dig(:controller) || ''
  return if sensitive_controller_keywords.none? { |keyword| controller.include?(keyword) }
  if !value.instance_of?(String)
    value.gsub!(/./, '*') unless !value.instance_of?(String)
  else
    # TODO: need a method for non-strings...
  end
end
```

What can I do to filter all values including non-strings?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are hoping to achieve? Right now this question is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: @engineersmnky I updated the question. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you

Comment: All you did was copy the body form the linked post, which you said was not working for you. I was hoping you could provide some context to the question because you simply said *"I need to filter string and non-string values"* which includes everything. To answer that question would simply be [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25955802/1978251) from the same post

Comment: Sorry, I think there should be enough info now @engineersmnky